# Turn Disjunctive Normal Form into only AND and NOT statements

Tags: logic, computer-science, boolean-algebra, disjunctive-normal-form

I'm working on implementing logic gates and want to implement an OR gate using only AND and NOT gates.

I came up with this canonical form for the OR function. $$Or(x, y) = (\lnot{x} \land y) \lor (x \land \lnot y) \lor (x \land y)$$ $$= y \lor (x \land \lnot y)$$

Then, working with DeMorgan's laws, I tried (following from above):

$$= \lnot(\lnot y) \lor \lnot(\lnot(x \land \lnot y))$$
$$= \lnot(\lnot y \land \lnot(x \land \lnot y))$$

But I can't figure out how to simplify it any further. Am I missing something or is this it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just start with the double negation and then apply De Morgan's law:

$$x\lor y = \lnot(\lnot( x\lor y)) = \lnot (\lnot x \land \lnot y)$$

Comment: That's so much smarter, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! I am glad I could help.